# How to call APIs in containers and pass response to presentational props, in React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm following davezuko's react-redux sample: https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit

Great starter kit for sure, but I'm facing some issues considering the next simple task.

I have a REST API sending json data via GET. I want to take the data, and pass it to the presentational component via props. I have no problem sending the ajax call action function via props, and execute it, but cannot find the optimal (and best practice) way to pass only retrieved json data on success.

I'm following Redux docs and examples, but there're some changes with my starter-kit.

**ACTION:**

```
export const getDetectedPersonList = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {    
    //return {
      dispatch({
        type  : GET_DETECTED_PERSON_LIST,
        payload : fetch("http://localhost:8080/FacialVideoDetector/detectedPersonsListWS")
          .then(function(response) {
            if (response.status >= 400) {
              console.log("Error " + response.status + " in the AJAX call")
              throw new Error("Bad response from server");
            }
              return response.json();
            })
            //.then(function(detections) {  })       
        })
      //}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this would be

```
export const getDetectedPersonList = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {    
        return fetch("http://localhost:8080/FacialVideoDetector/detectedPersonsListWS")
                    .then(function(response) {
                        if (response.status >= 400) {
                            console.log("Error " + response.status + " in the AJAX call")
                            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
                        }
                        dispatch({
                            type  : GET_DETECTED_PERSON_LIST,
                            payload : response.json()
                        }); 
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        dispatch({
                            type  : ERROR_PERSON_LIST,
                            payload : error
                        }); 
                    });
    });
}
```

Comment: But in this case you're returning a promise to the browser, leaving the component state with no data at first time, and no data at rendering (debugging it only logs the promise). What about this option (dispathing on .then function, when you can asure the browser you're sending a real response):